# p-norms with smaller and bigger powers

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $1<p<r<\infty$. Show that $\|x\|_r\le \|x\|_p$. [We already know that $\|x\|_\infty\le\|x\|_p$ for any $1<p<\infty$].

Would someone please give me a viable hint?

Comment: I assume you are working in $\ell_p$? Or $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $p$-norm?

Comment: No, in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
\begin{align*}
\|x\|_r
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^r\right)^{1/r} \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^{r-p}|x_i|^p\right)^{1/r} \\
&\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\|x\|_\infty^{r-p}|x_i|^p\right)^{1/r} \\
&= \|x\|_\infty^{(r-p)/r}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{1/r} \\
&= \|x\|_\infty^{(r-p)/r}\|x\|_p^{p/r} \\
&\le \ \cdots
\end{align*}
and don't forget what you already know.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: @sequence What about now? I've added one more term.

Comment: Do you mean the RHS is $\ge$ the LHS? @JohnGriffin

Comment: @sequence Yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how to continue your chain of inequalities.

Comment: @sequence I've added a couple more. I'm certain you can finish from here.